# JNI, cast between jobect and jthrowable

Tags: java, exception, java-native-interface

I need raise an exception from C++ code. Raised exception must contain text and code of error. 
So common form:

```
ThrowNew(jclass clazz, const char *msg)
```

is not applicable. That is why I want create my own instance of java class:

```
public class MyException extends Exception
```

that contains one more property for code. But JNI interface has only declaration for

```
Throw(jthrowable obj)
```

Is it correct to cast instance of MyException to jthrowable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the JVM jthrowable is an instance of java.lang.Throwable so if you instantiate the exception in your JNI code and cast it, it should work.

Comment: @Daff :) I have already tried, it is really works, but would it work on all platforms or using some new JDK?

Comment: I'm using it in Linux and Windows and didn't have a problem. Since it is part of the JVM (and Exceptions have always been a part of Java) you shouldn't expect any problems.

Comment: Would love to see a code example/snippet of this as I am going through this process right now myself!